# Topological map induced from group homomorphism of fundamental group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

The fundamental group operation can be considered as a functor $\pi_1:\textbf{Top}\to\textbf{Group}$.

Meanwhile, we know that for any group $G$, there exists a topological space (CW complex) such that $\pi_1(X_G)=G$. My question is: Given a group homomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$, is there always exists a continuous map of CW complexes $f_\varphi:X_G\to X_H$?

I tried to look at Hatcher, but seems nothing like this was mentioned. Thanks in advance in answering.

Comment: Could Hatcher's Proposition 1B.9 be something like what you're looking for?

Comment: Not quite, Theorem 1B.9 is only for $K(G,1)$ space, meaning fundamental group is fixed to be $G$. I would like to consider arbitrary pair of groups $G$, $H$.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't you just choose your spaces $X_G$ and $X_H$ to be $K(G,1)$ and $K(H, 1)$?

Comment: Oh I see, the theorem just requires the first topological space to be CW complex. 
However, it is I wanted a theorem where there is no restriction on $Y$. As $Y\in K(G,1)$ implies it has to have a contractible universal covering.

Comment: Is the question essentially whether every homorphism $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow\pi_1(Y)$ arises from a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ for any spaces $X$ and $Y$? Or do you want an existential quantifier on one or both of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Not from a map of topological space, but whether a map on the level of fundamental group induces a map of topological space in general. i.e., the inverse engineering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true for general $Y$ with $\pi_1(Y)=H$. The [obstruction class](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/lecture-1.pdf) is in $H^3(X,\pi_2Y)$.***

To say a bit more, given a homomorphism $\rho:G \to H$,  (after contracting $1$-skeletons) define maps $f_1:X^{(1)} \to Y$ by mapping generators for the fundamental group to generators. Since we have a group homomorphism, relations are satisfied, and in $X,Y$ such relations are $2$-cells, and so there is no problem extending this to a cellular map $f_2:X^{(2)} \to Y$.

After this, however, we are out of such luck. If $X$ is the [presentation complex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex) for $G$, then this is fine, but otherwise we have an obstruction cocycle that lives in $H^3(X,\pi_2 Y)$.

As mentioned before, when $Y=K(G,1)$, we know that $\pi_2(Y)=0$ and terefore such an obstruction doesn't exist, so we can extend to $X^{(3)}$, and to extend further we have another class in $H^4(X,\pi_3(Y))$, and so on, but $\pi_i(Y)=0$ for all $i>1$, and thus all of these obstructions vanish. As mentioned in the comments, this can be proven without this language (although basically the same idea) in Hatcher 1B.9.

A concrete counter-example would be finding a continuous map $f:\mathbb RP^3 \to \mathbb RP^2$ inducing the identity on $\mathbb Z/2$. One shows that this is impossible (without obstruction theory) by using the cup product on cohomology (see the proof of the Borsuk Ulam theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem).

This news is not so bad, since the assignment $G \to K(G,1)$ can be made functorial, and in this case, we can always realize group homomorphisms as continuous maps between *some* choice of spaces.

---

***We should assume here that $Y$ is a [simple space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_space) to make this more faimiliar, but we can in fact have an equivalent formulation by using local coefficients for cohomology.

Comment: I see what you meant. So it's like if the concerned pair of topological space are both 2-complex, then it is possible. But if it is of dimension >=3, then not always.  Am I right?

Comment: yes, its actually enough for $X$ to be a 2-complex, or alternatively for the higher homotopy of $Y$ to vanish. The real condition is the obstruction cocycle vanishing altogether in all dimensions.